# List missing data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm currently preparing a report in PowerBI where I need to list out missing items from a list of potential options. The values are categorical variables that are used to classify each entry into a log. I have a reference table and a list of manually entered values which I can get to show missing rows in a table that looks like this example.

[image]

My report has a pie chart showing the spread of the entered values, so the list is to show the complementary missing values. I am trying to work out a measure or calculated column that will show true/false for the blank cells in entered vals so I can use the reference list to filter only those values that are false.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DAX measure to check if a cell is blank or not

```
 Measure= IF(ISBLANK(Table1[reference]),"False","True")
```

Comment: The table that I shared above contains data from two separate df's, how would I link it so that it knows to compare the two columns to each other? Because this information is a categorical variable used to classify broader data in the spreadsheet. So I need it to say out of all these possible categories we are missing x, y ,z.